# How to create a hidden admin with a parental controls account? 

Tags: windows-vista, user-accounts, parental-controls

I was wondering if it would be possible to enable the hidden account admin

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

With a parental controls account? When I try to run as admin it never works and needs a password. Please help!

Comment: Are you saying you are a user under an account with parental controls, but you want to create a hidden admin account?

Answer (score 1):

This trick has been around since Windows XP. There is a SpecialAccounts Key that probably already exists, but if you don't have it - it can be created.

In regedit:

Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`

If there is not a sub-key under `Winlogon`, right click on the Winlogon entry and select `New > Key`

Name this new Key `SpecialAccounts`

Right click on `SpecialAccounts` and select `New > Key`

Name this new Key `UserList`

With the UserList selected, right click in the right pane of regedit and select `New > DWORD (32bit) Value`

This new DWORD value will be the name of your account EG: `Bob Dole` or `user93975` - whatever user name you want hidden.

Comment: To make this new Key Userlist you will need an admin pass

Comment: @user93975 so you don't want this hidden account to have a password?

Comment: Nope. It's fine w/o one I just need to be able to hide and unhide it once I'm done using it to disable Parental controls. It's sort of like that cmd command with uses the net user but I can't run as admin because I have parental controls on my acc

Comment: @user93975 so you are trying to circumvent the parental controls that have been placed on  your account?

Comment: Yes or get around it to download skype lol

Comment: You're asking the wrong people...

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious why you want to enable the hidden admin account in the first place? It's a well known attack vector, making your system less secure.

You can control Parental Controls from any admin account.

If you are using the Web console to control Parental Controls, you'll need to create a separate live account for each admin account and give them permission.

Comment: I assume the user he is trying to enforce parental controls on may try to get through if they see the admin account...

Comment: You can hide any user created account.  Yet it is **still** more secure than the builtin one.